# Use ipfs-core to set up node in browser with reactjs

Tags: reactjs, frontend, ipfs, js-ipfs

I'm trying to set up a local ipfs node for frontend users. I came across the "ipfs-core" module: https://www.npmjs.com/package/ipfs-core?activeTab=readme

When trying to instantiate the ipfs node I get the error "ipfs-core" can't be resolved. I then tried it with "ipfs-core-utils", but nothing seemed to work:

```
import * as IPFS from 'ipfs-core';

function App({}){
    const ipfs = IPFS.create();
```

results in:

```
Module not found: Can't resolve 'ipfs-core' in 'D:...
```

I also tried with required. I tried version 0.4.1 (latest) and 0.4.1.
I appreciate any help.